# From where can I get a library for c which will help me to write a C program to decrypt through 3DES in CBC mode?

Tags: 3des

I want to write a simple program where I can call the functions from a library and pass them the encrypted data as input and get the output as the decrypted data.
Which C library would be suitable for this.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org) will probably be your best bet. It's available on most systems, and has functions for doing triple-DES (e.g. DES_ede3_cbc_encrypt). See [the des(3) man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/des.html) for more information.

Most Linux distributions will have a development package for openssl which contains the header files for the library. On Debian-based distros (like Ubuntu), do `sudo apt-get install openssl-dev`. Alternatively, you can download the [library source](http://openssl.org/source/) and compile it yourself.

Comment: I visited this site sometime back but there is no option to download the library file over there.

Comment: The function which they have told that does the encryption is 
void DES_ncbc_encrypt(const unsigned char *input, unsigned char *output,long length, DES_key_schedule *schedule, DES_cblock *ivec,int enc);
I wanted to see what are the data types of these parameters so that I can pass suitable values. But not able to get the library file.

Comment: Updated answer to include download info. The data types would be defined in `openssl/des.h`, which can be found in your Include path (`/usr/include/` on my Ubuntu system).

Comment: I got the function named DES_ncbc_encrypt in des.h but how do I pass suitable values to the parameters untill I know what datatypes are used in parameter. In des.h only function declaration is there not the definition. So what value should I pass in the parameters while passing the values. theparameters which I have doubt about are DES_key_schedule *schedule,DES_cblock *ivec,int enc